# KDevelop settings export possible?

Tags: kdevelop

I'm a newbie to KDevelop.
Played around with it, now I have a question about project settings.

Is it possible to export detailed settings such as launch configurations or additional make options?

In the KDevelop 4 project file, say "myproj.kdev4", only basic information such as

```
[Project]
Manager=KDevCustomMakeManager
Name=myproj
```

are provided.
It should be nice if the user could export more detailed settings for a project.

Comment: Just found an answer! Such configurations were written in a hidden directory, .kdev4.

Answer (score 0):

those settings are stored in .kdev4/ subfolder, you can export that.

But it's not ment to me shared (or put under version control)